# Viewing lilith log files using the log viewer

Tags: logback

I use logback version 0.9.29 and lilith v0..9.43 in my application to generate a .lilith file using a FileAppender. I see the appender is created and that the app-log.lilith file is also created successfully. 
The encoder configuration i use for the lilith File Appender is

```
    <encoder class="de.huxhorn.lilith.logback.encoder.ClassicLilithEncoder">
        <IncludeCallerData>true</IncludeCallerData>
    </encoder>
```

When i run the lilith logviewer and try to open the generated lilith file, i'm prompted to index the selected log file and then i get an error telling me the lilith file is invalid.
I can view the contents of the lilith log file, it seems to be just a regular text file.
Any ideas on what might be wrong? and why the log viewer thinks the file is invalid?

Does the ClassicLilithEncoder just create a text file? or is that an indication that the file was not encoded correctly and that is why the logviewer considers it invalid.